# How to conditionally set ::after sass rule in a react app

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

hope your weekends are going great! I am just trying to figure out how I can conditionally set the `&::after {}` rule. Please see below to what I mean:

```scss
@import "../global/parts";
.nav__item {
  position: relative;
  @include _minWidthMedium {
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }
  &::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    background-color: $orange;
    bottom: -3px;
    transform: scaleX(0);
    transition: transform 460ms ease-out;
    transform-origin: right;
    perspective: 1000px;
    backface-visibility: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
    z-index: 70;
  }
  &:hover,
  &.nav__item_active {
    &::after {
      transform: scaleX(1);
      transform-origin: left;
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, in the first &::after rule, I am setting the background color to orange that renders an orange underline after hover. However, there are multiple places where this nav__item is being used and I would like to keep the code dry.

What I am trying to do is have background-color set to 'none' if the link is a main CTA, rather than just a regular nav item.
Is there any way to do this?

I have tried to search relevant topics on this but couldn't find anything.

Comment: Given you tagged your question with `styled-components`, are you_actually_ using styled-components? That I'm aware, you can't use SCSS in styled-components.

Comment: @code sorry, that was my bad. I wasn't  styled-components. I will remove the tag.

Comment: Is it a react app? This is easy to solve using js. You should add your jsx here.